# Simple .htaccess rule to redirect subfolder

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How do i edit the .htaccess file to redirect all links in a subdirectory to another subdirectory

*inactive url*

**http://example.com/dir/archive/AnythingHere**

*redirect location*

**http://example.com/dir/new/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dir/archive/(.*)$ /dir/new/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Make sure to place this rule as **very first** rule in your WP .htaccess file